# problem with the automatic jump function - doodlejump pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I programmed doodlejump. So far I have the Doodle and 2 platforms, but at the moment my Doodle only jumps on one platform and not on the others.
But I've only had this problem since I added more than 1 platform. Does anyone have an idea why this could be?

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v7Oa.jpg)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.